# Fundamental counting principle for orbits going wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

maybe that's idiot, but I'm missing something here. Let $X = \{(123),(132),(124),(142),(134),(143),(234),(243) \}$, $A_4$ act on $X$ by conjugation (inner automorphisms) and $x = (123)$, then $4 =|\mathscr{O}(x)| = |G|/|G_x| = 12/|G_x|$. However, $G_x = \{ 1 \}$ !!!!What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stabilizer is not the identity, because your action in conjugation, not multiplication. Every group element stabilizes itself under conjugation, and every power of a group element stabilizes the original element, too.

Comment: I agree, but this leads to another problem. $|G_x| = 5$ now.

Comment: Check again, you should find three elements in $G_x = \{ g \in A_4 : g x g^{-1} = x \}$.  In the case of the conjugation action, the stabilizer of $x$ is often called the center of $x$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce But the centralizer of $x$ will be composed by the powers of $(123)$, i.e, $(123)^k$ for $k = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2$. What's wrong? Am I missing something.

Comment: $(123)^{-1} = (123)^2$ and $(123)^{-2} = (123)$ :)

Comment: Now, I'm feeling a complete idiot. Thanks